# Quotient map into Compactification of Subspace

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and let $A \subseteq X$ be closed. Consider the following map from $X$ into the one point compactification of $X - A$, which we call $Y$.

$$f: X \rightarrow Y$$
$$x \mapsto x \text{ if } x \in X - A, x \mapsto \infty \text{ if } x \in A.$$

Is $f$ a quotient map? I'm convinced that it is, because it's so similar to the quotient map from $X \rightarrow X/A$ but I can't prove it.

Comment: If $X$ is a compact space, then $X/A$ is already compact to begin with. Its one point compactification will just add an isolated point.

Comment: The compactification of X-A. I meant the backslash as set difference.

Comment: oh right. sorry my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case where $X=[0, 1]$ is a closed interval and $A=(1/2, 1/3)$ is an open subinterval. Then $X-A$ is compact  disconnected space (disjoint pair of closed intervals) whose one point compactification ($X-A$ with an isolated point) is also disconnected. But if you want your map to be a quotient map then $Y$, the one point compactification on $X-A$ must be homeomorphic to $X/A$ as only elements in $A$ are identified. But as $X$ is connected, $X/A$ is also connected and hence cannot be homeomorphic to $Y$

**EDIT:** The statement is true when $A$ is closed. To shoe this note that all we have to do is show that $X\to Y$ is continuous as then the universal property of quotient map $X\to X/A$ will induce a map $X/A\to Y$ such that the composition is the original map. Then we would have a continuous bijection between compact hausdorff spaces and hence a homeomorphism. This will give that $X\to Y$ is a quotient map.

Now we need to show continuity. Now as $A$ is a closed subset of a compact hausdorff space, it is compact and $X-A$ is open. So an open set in $Y$ is either an open set in $X-A$ (and hence open in X), or an a compliment of a compact set in $X-A$ (which is again open) union the infinity point. The pullback of the first kind of open set is obviously open. For the second kind, the pullback of its compliment is a compact subset of $X-A$ and hence a closed subset of $X$, therefore the pullback of the open set is open.

Comment: $A$ should be a closed subset of $X$. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Again sorry for not reading the question completely :-). It works in that case i will edit the answer

Comment: the edit turned out to be bigger than the original answer :-)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much

Comment: Wait sorry are you saying that X and Y are homeomorphic?

Comment: No the map $X\to Y$ is just continuous. The induced map $X/A\to Y$ is a homeomorphism